# performance advising compilers - do such things exists?

Tags: c++

Working on a very CPU intensive project and was shocked to find ~100x difference between debug and release builds. I managed to track down some of the offending poorly performing code, but its clear that the compiler optimized away all the 'bad stuff' as it knew it was really irrelevant noise. THe main culprit was

```
for(auto x : xcoll)
```

instead of

```
for(auto &x : xcoll)
```

in a few places. Now you would think the compiler might go "are you sure you want to do that?". I just wonder if there are any compilers or other tools that would tell you.

You may ask - "why do you care, its only the debug build?". Well when I am debugging I need to get to the failure point. I was taking a long time, several minutes, to get there; v frustrating.

FYI , another big difference on hot code path `std::function` vs raw function pointers

Comment: That would be welcome. The 'auto' issue is something which Visual Studio 2019 will pick up: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/intellisense-code-linter-for-cpp/

Comment: Static analysers do more detailed checks than some compilers. Some compilers also have options to issue warnings about constructs that are deemed less effective by various measures (e.g. gcc has the `-Weffc++` option which gives warnings if code doesn't follow various guidelines from Scott Meyer's "Effective C++" series). But as a general rule,optimisation by a compiler is implemented as a long series of microptimisations that, when put together, give more optimial code - so the compiler doesn't necessarily have the means to access information which says "this source code is better than that"

Comment: @gast128 - well i am using vs2019, i will turn that on and see what is says.

Comment: @gast128 - ahh, I  dont have that version yet, nice to know its coming tho